# Intel Pin - How to only instrument child process

Tags: c++, intel-pin

I have a run.sh script:

`expr 1 + 1`

what I actually want to instrument is expr.
Here is My Pin tool's code(I only instrument indirect calls to avoid the output became to large):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2004-2021 Intel Corporation.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include "pin.H"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

pid_t trg_pid = 0;

 VOID print_ins(ADDRINT addr) {
    cout<<PIN_GetPid()<<'\t'<<trg_pid<<'\t'<<hex<<addr<<oct<<endl;
    
 }
 

// Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID* v)
{
    if(INS_IsCall(ins) && INS_IsIndirectControlFlow(ins))
    {
        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)print_ins, IARG_INST_PTR,IARG_END);
    }
    
}

BOOL FollowChild(CHILD_PROCESS cProcess, VOID* userData)
{
    int argcc;
    char ** argvv;
    CHILD_PROCESS_GetCommandLine(cProcess,&argcc,(const char* const**)&argvv);
    if(string(argvv[0]).find("expr") != string::npos)
    {
        trg_pid = PIN_GetPid();
        cout<<"trgpid : "<<trg_pid<<endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// This function is called when the application exits
VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID* v)
{
    // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
    cout<<"finish"<<endl;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    cerr << "This tool counts the number of dynamic instructions executed" << endl;
    cerr << endl << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() << endl;
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */
/*   argc, argv are the entire command line: pin -t <toolname> -- ...    */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize pin
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    PIN_AddFollowChildProcessFunction(FollowChild, 0);

    // Register Instruction to be called to instrument instructions
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);

    // Register Fini to be called when the application exits
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Start the program, never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

and I run Pin using the following command:

`/home/lzy/Desktop/pin-3.25-98650-g8f6168173-gcc-linux/pin -follow_execv -t /home/lzy/Desktop/pin-3.25-98650-g8f6168173-gcc-linux/source/tools/MyPinTool/obj-intel64/MyPinTool.so -- ./run.sh`

and the output:

```
256709  0   7f42258b185a
765305  0   7f422589f9fd
765305  0   7f422589f908
765305  0   7f422589f9fd
765305  0   7f422589f908
765305  0   7f42258b4dc7
765305  0   7f42258b4e81
765305  0   7f42258b4f3d
765305  0   7f42258b4ff9
765305  0   7f42258b50b4
765305  0   7f42258af5cf
765305  0   7f42258af99b
765305  0   7f422589a752
765305  0   7f422589a799
765305  0   7f42258af368
765305  0   7f42258b91fa
765305  0   7f4225898a53
765305  0   7f422589f9fd
765305  0   7f422589fd1b
765305  0   7f422589f908
765305  0   7f42258af368
765305  0   7f4225895a54
765305  0   7f4225895f4c
765305  0   7f42258af470
765305  0   7f42258a82d7
765305  0   7f42258a82d7
765305  0   7f42258a82d7
765305  0   7f42258a82d7
765305  0   7f42258b2d68
765305  0   7f42258a642b
765305  0   7f42258a64a0
765305  0   7f42258a36e9
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3091
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a3a8d
765305  0   7f42258a6524
765305  0   7f42258a6675
765305  0   7f422589786c
765305  0   7f42258a36e9
765305  0   7f422589847c
765305  0   7f422589847c
765305  0   55857ba33f0f
765305  0   7f4211abde66
765305  0   7f4211abdeb9
765305  0   7f4211abdd8e
765305  0   55857ba45061
765305  0   55857ba45061
765305  0   7f4211b091c8
765305  0   7f4211b09d25
765305  0   7f4211b0a047
765305  0   55857ba3bbfe
trgpid : 765310
256712  0   7fb6e21c885a
765310  0   7fb6e21b69fd
765310  0   7fb6e21b6908
765310  0   7fb6e21b69fd
765310  0   7fb6e21b6908
765310  0   7fb6e21cbdc7
765310  0   7fb6e21cbe81
765310  0   7fb6e21cbf3d
765310  0   7fb6e21cbff9
765310  0   7fb6e21cc0b4
765310  0   7fb6e21c65cf
765310  0   7fb6e21c699b
765310  0   7fb6e21b1752
765310  0   7fb6e21b1799
765310  0   7fb6e21c6368
765310  0   7fb6e21d01fa
765310  0   7fb6e21afa53
765310  0   7fb6e21b69fd
765310  0   7fb6e21b6d1b
765310  0   7fb6e21b6908
765310  0   7fb6e21c6368
765310  0   7fb6e21d01fa
765310  0   7fb6e21afa53
765310  0   7fb6e21b69fd
765310  0   7fb6e21b6d1b
765310  0   7fb6e21b6908
765310  0   7fb6e21c6368
765310  0   7fb6e21aca54
765310  0   7fb6e21c6368
765310  0   7fb6e21aca54
765310  0   7fb6e21acf4c
765310  0   7fb6e21c6470
765310  0   7fb6e21bf2d7
765310  0   7fb6e21bf2d7
765310  0   7fb6e21bf2d7
765310  0   7fb6e21bf2d7
765310  0   7fb6e21bf2d7
765310  0   7fb6e21c9d68
765310  0   7fb6e21bd42b
765310  0   7fb6e21bd4a0
765310  0   7fb6e21ba6e9
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21ba091
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21baa8d
765310  0   7fb6e21bd524
765310  0   7fb6e21bd675
765310  0   7fb6e21ae86c
765310  0   7fb6e21ba6e9
765310  0   7fb6e21af47c
765310  0   7fb6e21af47c
765310  0   7fb6e21af438
765310  0   7fb6e21af47c
765310  0   55690b901b4f
765310  0   7fb6ce26ce66
765310  0   7fb6ce26cd8e
765310  0   7fb6ce279c06
765310  0   7fb6e21bc0d0
765310  0   7fb6ce5c4192
765310  0   7fb6ce5c4192
765310  0   55690b90c5e2
765310  0   7fb6e21bc0d0
765310  0   7fb6ce2c3053
765310  0   7fb6ce2ce752
765310  0   7fb6ce2d0d5d
765310  0   7fb6ce2c1bed
765310  0   7fb6ce288493
765310  0   7fb6ce2c2227
765310  0   7fb6ce2cfa5d
2
765310  0   7fb6ce2cef78
finish
```

I want to filter the instruction executed in expr by using a global variable trg_pid, but trg_pid is still 0 after i changed its value in FollowChild. Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears `expr 1 + 1` uses the `execve` system call to execute the child program. An important feature of `execve` is that the process does not change, so the process ID will not change either.

The reason `trg_pid` remains 0 is because when the pintool calls `FollowChild`, only the parent program's version of `trg_pid` is set to the PID. This is because:

1. `Pin_AddFollowChildProcessFunction` executes *before* the child program executes.
2. Pin instruments both programs independently, i.e., they both have their own copy of `trg_pid`.

After `FollowChild` executes, the output you see is the result of instrumenting the child program, which has the same process ID as the parent but still has the default `trg_pid` value of 0.

The example you posted is kind of misleading because you do not see the process ID update until the call to `FollowChild` happens. In reality, something else changed the process ID. Based on an `strace`, it looks like there is a call to `vfork` shortly before `execve`. The child spawned by `vfork` executes `execve`. Your pintool does not currently track `vfork`. To do that, you can try to instrument fork functions via `PIN_AddForkFunction()`.

Comment: I think the parent process ID is 765305 and the child process ID is 765310